# MySQL PREPARE statement in stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepare

I have this sql file:

```
USE mydb;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS execSql;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE execSql (
                     IN sqlq VARCHAR(5000)
                      ) COMMENT 'Executes the statement'
BEGIN
  PREPARE stmt FROM sqlq;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

When I try to run it with

# cat file.sql | mysql -p

I get

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sqlq;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END' at line 5
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can only prepare and execute SQL that's a *string literal* or a [*user-defined variable*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) that contains the text of the statement.

Try this:

```
USE mydb;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS execSql;
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE execSql (IN sqlq VARCHAR(5000)) COMMENT 'Executes the statement'
BEGIN
  SET @sqlv = sqlq;
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlv;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Note that in a cursor, `FETCH [foo] INTO y`, inside the cursor you have to create a new `@yValue = y' and use @yValue for the prepared statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CONCATENATE`, `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` statements as bellow:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`products`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `generateMeritList`(
   IN `mastercategory_id` INT(11), 
   IN `masterschools_id` INT(11)
) NO SQL
BEGIN

  DECLARE total INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE conditions varchar(255) DEFAULT ''; 
  DECLARE finalQuery varchar(60000) DEFAULT '';

  IF mastercategory_id > 0 THEN
    SET conditions =  CONCAT(' AND app.masterschools_id = ', mastercategory_id);
  END IF;

  SET @finalQuery = CONCAT(
    "SELECT *
    FROM applications app
    INNER JOIN masterschools school ON school.id = app.masterschools_id
    WHERE app.status = 'active' ", conditions, " LIMIT ", total); 

   PREPARE stmt FROM @finalQuery;
   EXECUTE stmt;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but, besides the fact I already accepted mpf's answer about 5 years ago, I fail to understand how your post is supposed to answer my question.

Comment: @Dinesh Vaitage - I am sorry to say, this does not prevent SQL injection attacks. There is no parameters to use in the preparation of the statement. In other words, where is the @conditions?