# mysql prepared statement unable to execute. Getting error 1064

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TOUR_TRANSFER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE TOUR_TRANSFER(in_search CHAR(80),tbl CHAR(80),clmn CHAR(80))
BEGIN
DECLARE selstmt,sel_cmd VARCHAR(100);
BEGIN -- for rubric table
        SET selstmt=concat('SELECT ',clmn,' INTO @tbl_data FROM ',tbl,' WHERE ',clmn, ' REGEXP "', in_search,'"');
        select selstmt;
        PREPARE sel_cmd FROM @selstmt;
        EXECUTE sel_cmd;
        select @tbl_data;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE sel_cmd;
END;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I am getting an error (1064) in the prepare statement whereas I am able to execute it manually.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Also, please share your code - perhaps you having a mistake in the code side and not on the SQL side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few syntactical issues. Try this one now

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TOUR_TRANSFER;
//
CREATE PROCEDURE TOUR_TRANSFER(in_search CHAR(80),tbl CHAR(80),clmn CHAR(80))
BEGIN
DECLARE selstmt, tbl_data, sel_cmd VARCHAR(100);
SET @selstmt=concat('SELECT ',clmn,' INTO @tbl_data FROM ',tbl,' WHERE ',clmn, '   REGEXP "', in_search,'"');
select @selstmt;
PREPARE sel_cmd FROM @selstmt;
EXECUTE sel_cmd;
select @tbl_data;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE sel_cmd;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I am getting the same error \n 13:33:10 call TOUR_TRANSFER('avinash','user','name') Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

Comment: there is some issue in the prepare statement I am able to create the procedure without any syntax errors but unable to call it as it throws 1064 error

Answer (score 0):

Swap your first two lines and change them to look like this.  You want to drop the procedure first, then set the delimiter for your stored proc.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TOUR_TRANSFER;

DELIMITER $$
```

You also appear to have an extra set of `BEGIN` and `END` statements.  You can remove the inner ones.

That would get your code looking like this.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TOUR_TRANSFER;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE TOUR_TRANSFER(in_search CHAR(80),tbl CHAR(80),clmn CHAR(80))
BEGIN
DECLARE selstmt,sel_cmd VARCHAR(100);
        SET selstmt=concat('SELECT ',clmn,' INTO @tbl_data FROM ',tbl,' WHERE ',clmn, ' REGEXP "', in_search,'"');
        select selstmt;
        PREPARE sel_cmd FROM @selstmt;
        EXECUTE sel_cmd;
        select @tbl_data;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE sel_cmd;
END

$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here's a link to another question related to using prepared statements within a stored proc.  See the answer for an example.

[MySQL PREPARE statement in stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895383/mysql-prepare-statement-in-stored-procedures)

Comment: If I remove the $$ on the line `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TOUR_TRANSFER $$` I get a syntax error The new code is `DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TOUR_TRANSFER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE TOUR_TRANSFER(in_search CHAR(80),tbl CHAR(80),clmn CHAR(80))
BEGIN
DECLARE selstmt,sel_cmd VARCHAR(100);
  SET selstmt=concat('SELECT ',clmn,' INTO @tbl_data FROM ',tbl,' WHERE ',clmn, ' REGEXP "', in_search,'"');
  select selstmt;
  PREPARE sel_cmd FROM @selstmt;
  EXECUTE sel_cmd;
  select @tbl_data;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE sel_cmd;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
call TOUR_TRANSFER('avinash','user','name')



`

Answer (score 0):

This is because there's a syntax error in your code. Befin Statement should have an end and from your code the end statement is commented out see sample code below

```
DELIMITER $$;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TOUR_TRANSFER $$;

CREATE PROCEDURE TOUR_TRANSFER(in_search CHAR(80),tbl CHAR(80),clmn CHAR(80)) BEGIN DECLARE selstmt,sel_cmd VARCHAR(100); 
BEGIN 
-- for rubric table SET selstmt=concat('SELECT ',clmn,' INTO @tbl_data FROM ',tbl,' WHERE ',clmn, ' REGEXP "', in_search,'"'); select selstmt; PREPARE sel_cmd FROM @selstmt; EXECUTE sel_cmd; select @tbl_data; DEALLOCATE PREPARE sel_cmd; 
END; END$$ DELIMITER
```

Add a new line on you code and it should work fine.

Comment: When I call the stored procedure after creating it then I get a prepared statement produced using 'SET selstmt=concat('SELECT ',clmn,' INTO @tbl_data FROM ',tbl,' WHERE ',clmn, ' REGEXP "', in_search,'"');
  select selstmt;'line in the code. If I execute the generated statement manually(separately) it works well but it does not run in the stored procedure