# Pivot a table and display n ordered time series

Tags: mysql, time-series, pivot-table

I have a table named "readings" which contains data from sensors with the following columns:

```
id    id_device    date                   value
1     1            2015-01-01 00:00:00    0.2
2     2            2015-01-01 00:00:00    0.7
3     1            2015-01-01 00:00:10    0.3
4     2            2015-01-01 00:00:10    0.8
5     1            2015-01-01 00:00:20    0.4
6     2            2015-01-01 00:00:20    0.9
```

And I want to transform it to this table in a single query:

```
date                   device_id_1     device_id_2
2015-01-01 00:00:00    0.2             0.7
2015-01-01 00:00:10    0.3             0.8
2015-01-01 00:00:20    0.4             0.9
```

I've found that doing this is called "pivoting a table" but I've only found how to sum values, not how to order them in time series

I've tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT(date) FROM readings
```

and then inside the results loop, querying again for each sensor

```
SELECT value FROM readings WHERE date=$date AND id_device=$id
```

But I'm sure that this is not very efficient because it is a lot of queries (one query for each value)

How the sql query would be like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT r.id,
       r.`date`,
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(r.device_id = 1,r.`VALUE`,NULL)) AS device_id_1,
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(r.device_id = 2,r.`VALUE`,NULL)) AS device_id_2
FROM readings r
GROUP BY r.`DATE`
ORDER BY r.`DATE` ASC;

+----+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
| id | date                | device_id_1 | device_id_2 |
+----+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 | 2015-10-01 10:00:00 | 2           | 0.5         |
|  3 | 2015-10-01 10:01:00 | 3.1         | 7.5         |
+----+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And here a Version for dynamic device_id's

```
SELECT  group_concat( 
    "GROUP_CONCAT(IF(device_id = ",
    device_id,",`value`,NULL)) AS device_id_",
    device_id
    SEPARATOR ',\n') INTO @sql_mid
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT device_id FROM readings ORDER BY device_id) AS r
ORDER BY device_id;

SELECT CONCAT("SELECT id, `date`, ", @sql_mid, " FROM readings GROUP BY `DATE` ORDER BY `DATE` ASC") INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

It generates all Columns

```
+----+---------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| id | date                | device_id_1 | device_id_2 | device_id_3 |
+----+---------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 | 2015-10-01 10:00:00 | 2           | 0.5         | NULL        |
|  3 | 2015-10-01 10:01:00 | 3.1         | 7.5         | NULL        |
|  5 | 2015-10-01 10:11:00 | NULL        | NULL        | 9.9         |
+----+---------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @Adarsh Gangadharan - I have add a Version in my Answer for dynamic device ids.

Comment: How can I convert this into a stored procedure. I tried. But instead of returning the results, it returns the query.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895383/mysql-prepare-statement-in-stored-procedures