# Filtering EAV table with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-attribute-value

I have 2 tables:

Table `objects`:

```
object_id | object_group_id
```

Table `attributes`:

```
attr_id | attr_object_id | attr_property_id | attr_value
```

Now, I want to get all `object_id` where `object_group_id = 1` and filters two attributes:

```
(attr_property_id = 1 AND attr_value <= '100000')
   AND 
(attr_property_id = 2 AND attr_value > '2000')
```

I was trying to construct some queries, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM objects as o

/* filter1 join */
INNER JOIN 
    attributes AS f1 
        ON 
    o.object_id = f1.attr_object_id 
        AND 
    f1.attr_property_id = 1

/* filter2 join */
INNER JOIN 
    attributes AS f2 
        ON 
    f1.attr_object_id = f2.attr_object_id 
        AND 
    f2.attr_property_id = 2

WHERE 
    o.object_group_id = 1
       AND
   f1.attr_value <= '100000'
       AND
   f2.attr_value > '2000'
```

... but still can't get what I need.

Comment: Do you want to have 1 row with attr_values or 2 row. Please show a sample from the result you want

Comment: I want to get one row per one object, wich are matching two key-value conditions in attributes.

Comment: look at this. it generates your query as pivot table
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33350524/pivot-a-table-and-display-n-ordered-time-series/33351008?noredirect=1#comment54499334_33351008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After couple hours of combining and trying, I finally did:

```
    SELECT * FROM objects as o

/* filter1 join */
INNER JOIN 
    attributes AS f1 
        ON 
    o.object_id = f1.attr_object_id 
        AND 
    f1.attr_property_id = 1
        AND
    f1.attr_value <= '100000'

/* filter2 join */
INNER JOIN 
    attributes AS f2 
        ON 
    f1.attr_object_id = f2.attr_object_id 
        AND 
    f2.attr_property_id = 2
        AND
    f2.attr_value > '2000'

WHERE 
    o.object_group_id = 1
```

I was too close, and done this by moving all filter conditions to `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with an alternative, possibly more understandable approach.
Let's look at the problem step by step in a simple example. Our initial tables can have the following data:

*objects* table:

```
object_id  |  object_group_id
    1                1
    2                1
    3                1
    4                2
    5                1
    6                1
```

*attributes* table:

```
attr_id | attr_object_id  |  attr_property_id  |  attr_value
    1           1                   1                50000
    2           1                   1                75000
    3           1                   1               150000
    4           1                   2                 1000
    5           1                   2                 5000
    6           2                   1                30000
    7           2                   1               200000
    8           2                   2                 7000
    9           3                   1               500000
   10           3                   2                 1000
   11           4                   1                90000
   12           4                   2                 6000
   13           5                   1               150000
   14           5                   2                 3000
   15           6                   1                70000
   16           6                   2                 1000
```

I. We start working with the second table since the main part of the problem is actually in it, and we apply our filter directly as:

```
SELECT * from attributes
WHERE (attr_property_id = 1 AND attr_value <= 100000) OR (attr_property_id = 2 AND attr_value > 2000)
```

Notice that we use an "OR" between conditions since we need to get all the rows from the *attributes* table that apply to *one* OR *another* condition

The result is the following:

```
attr_id | attr_object_id  |  attr_property_id  |  attr_value
    1           1                   1                50000
    2           1                   1                75000
    5           1                   2                 5000
    6           2                   1                30000
    8           2                   2                 7000
   11           4                   1                90000
   12           4                   2                 6000
   14           5                   2                 3000
   15           6                   1                70000
```

II. Now we need to take only those *attr_object_id* that have both *attr_property_id* "1" and "2" in the above result, i.e. those *attr_object_id* adhere to our initial problem's filter. We can achieve that by the following query:

```
SELECT attr_object_id, count(distinct(attr_property_id)) FROM attributes
WHERE (attr_property_id = 1 AND attr_value <= 100000) OR (attr_property_id = 2 AND attr_value > 2000)
GROUP BY attr_object_id
```

The result is:

```
attr_object_id  |  count
      1              2
      2              2
      4              2
      5              1
      6              1
```

You can see from the above result that *attr_object_id* with "1", "2" and "4" satisfy both our initial problem's filters, but "5" and "6" are only one of the filters.
Let's filter out "5" and "6" now:

```
SELECT attr_object_id FROM attributes
WHERE (attr_property_id = 1 AND attr_value <= 100000) OR (attr_property_id = 2 AND attr_value > 2000)
GROUP BY attr_object_id
HAVING count(distinct(attr_property_id)) = 2
```

And we're getting:

```
attr_object_id
      1
      2
      4
```

III. At this point, the main part of the problem is solved and we only need to apply the filter from the *objects* table, i.e. *object_group_id* = 1. The query for this one is straightforward, we just need to INNER JOIN *objects* and *attributes* tables and add a condition to the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT attr_object_id FROM attributes
INNER JOIN objects on attributes.attr_object_id = objects.object_id
WHERE object_group_id = 1 AND ((attr_property_id = 1 AND attr_value <= 100000) OR (attr_property_id = 2 AND attr_value > 2000))
GROUP BY attr_object_id
HAVING count(distinct(attr_property_id)) = 2
```

The final result for our example is:

```
attr_object_id
      1
      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I am not sure why do you have the last lines

```
SELECT
  o.object_id, o.object_group_id,
  f1.attr_value AS val1,
  f2.attr_value AS val2,
FROM objects AS o
LEFT JOIN attributes f1 ON o.object_id = f1.attr_object_id AND f1.attr_property_id = 1
LEFT JOIN attributes f1 ON o.object_id = f2.attr_object_id AND f2.attr_property_id = 2
WHERE
    o.object_group_id = 1
AND
   f1.attr_value <= '100000'
AND
   f2.attr_value > '2000';
```

remove this lines and test it also

```
AND
   f1.attr_value <= '100000'
AND
   f2.attr_value > '2000';
```

Comment: I've tried with `LEFT JOIN`, but it never compares more than one key-value pair. It splits all key-value pairs into seperate rows. So I can't compare both.